# Azure Search indexer does not pick up update to null

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

In the cosmos db I have array element "X" and it's mapped to in the index field "X" Collection(Edm.string). If I update X to null then changes does not reflect in the Azure search. Indexer picks up the timestamp change but actual value does not show up in the index. (but if you assign any value, it's show up in the index). Basically when you make your element null, index does not show "null" instead it shows old value.

Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: One thing to consider is [the conditional skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-conditional) that could map null to some other value such as an empty string. There's also a ternary operator that you can use in expressions that may work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the field to an empty array.

Setting a fields value to null removes it from the index (in contrast to setting it to an empty string or 0).
Collections are, well, collections of values. You can remove values from the collection, but not the collection itself.